# Is there a way to install a drop-down with all site pages in WP-Editor?

Tags: wp-editor

I design pages while in low-internet areas so I wonder: **Is there a way to include a drop-down of all site pages in WP Editor for easier navigation?** Call me lazy, but I think others would benefit from this as well so that we can load another page directly rather than searching for it.

Update: The dropdown will simply show all pages in the tree and then go to edit them when you choose one.

Comment: what will this dropdown do ? go to the edition of the selected page ?

Comment: You can add a dropdown made with `wp_dropdown_pages` combine with mce filters and actions.